# OWIN Cookie Authentication and Cross Domain AngularJS Client

Tags: angularjs, authentication, cookies, signalr, owin

Application Setup

Client - AngularJS (hosted at client.domain.com)

API + SignalR - Hosted at api.domain.com

SignalR setup class

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
    });

    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableJSONP = true
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
}
```

And I do following from Authentication service

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, myuserid));
ClaimsIdentity id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, id);
```

Authentication response looks like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 556
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=pvasgf4q2klfbmk4oojqkxm5; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=1lBbz_FRNvxt1AhwkzZHFoiyhyZgsasNXStV3SbjQUHt0hqxTG--yXtjYNquB4zmQn-6M99pqHRPHaT4uf8g1JAnqg5WldD65IJ_FxYoEucf_WvV1fY4pwf774Cyo6fhI5nVk9Z6fdpjY422eo0GIibIMhaV9QvHNaiSsbFO0koT-CnhQuD5DED_418nP7m4FBbXdwIbFM_squ0bVYKXuB35jm57zVk9hUVWdlPmWxc; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 30 Dec 2014 00:20:29 GMT
```

When I the app makes request to signalr/negotiate, it receives 401 (unauthorized) because the cookie received in authentication response is not being sent with signalr request.

Is there anything I am missing?

### UPDATE 1

All of above works fine when client and api are hosted in the same domain like this.

Client - www.domain.com/client

API - www.domain.com/api

### UPDATE 2

Upon digging a little further, I realized that the issue is not related to signalr at all. I wrote a light client just to see if I can authenticate and follow that up with a simple get request. I hosted the client at api.domain.com/lightclient and made api requests to api.domain.com/api everything works. The following get request has the authentication cookie. However, when I moved the client to client.domain.com, browser removes the cookie.